# How to give div content fixed size

Tags: html

I have `div` with width style 65%.

Then I put an `img` inside this `div` without any css style attributes, but this `img` width above 65% and move out side the `div` frame.

How can I adjust the `img` width without give it any css style?

```html
<div style="width: 65%">
    <img src="assets/images/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_edit_1.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you have against css rules? It certainly is much more elegant that your inline style approach.

Comment: This is not possible! You have to use CSS to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Set as a background image

```
<div class="product-image" style="width: 65%;  background-image:url(assets/images/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_edit_1.jpg');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, could you clarify?

In any case, you can, and you can't, depending on how you look at it. Most images are pixel 'grids' and will have a set size in pixels, no matter what you do.

You can set the size in HTML:

```
<img src="assets/images/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_edit_1.jpg" height="42" width="42">
```

But this will not actually resize the image, just push it together or stretch it, so your quality will suffer. (Same with CSS) And these days this is seen as a bad way of doing this.

If you cannot target the image directly, maybe targeting the image as a child of its container works for you?

```
div img {
 width: 100px;
 height 100px;
}
```

But really, you should explain more what you want to do and why your limitations are what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important inside your div tag style.
CSS rules marked !important take precedence over later rules. Normally in CSS the rules work from top to bottom, so if you assigned a new style to an element further down the style sheet or in a secondary style sheet then the later rule would take precedence. !important ensures that this rule has precedence.

For example in your case:

```
<div style="width: 65% !important">
    <img src="assets/images/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_edit_1.jpg">
</div>
```

The first rule now has precedence so the later rule is ignored and the img style will take after it's div.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your image is bigger then your div because the css does not apply to the image,
try using

html

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="assets/images/Orion_Nebula_-_Hubble_2006_mosaic_edit_1.jpg">
</div>
```

css

```
.image{
    width: 65%;
}

.image img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

this will make a div width the width of 65% of the page and the image will be 100% of the div width.